# Chrome breakpoint system randomly fails, until reboot

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, create-react-app, chrome-debugging

I can debug just fine using Chrome devtools for a while, but at some point my breakpoints stop working. They are still enabled (darker blue in the gutter). "debugger;" statements still break. Quitting and restarting Chrome does not solve the problem, but completely rebooting my machine does.

Does this ring bells for anyone? I have not tried uninstalling and reinstalling chrome.

Chrome is current as of today: Version 74.0.3729.169 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Using create-react-app, VSCode, can supply version #s but doubt they are relevant.

Any help appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Sounds like it has something to do with Chrome itself. I would recommend reinstalling it

Comment: Can you put a reproducible example of the issue on [Glitch](https://glitch.com)?

Comment: @BrianLe Unfortunately the problem still happens after a reinstall

Comment: @KayceBasques Unfortunately it is intermittent so not necessarily reproducible even with my whole code base.